# Using core data instead of dataModel

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data

I am trying to follow a tutorial https://github.com/wannabegeek/ExpandableTableView

but I need the data to be persistent, so I guess I should use `core data`. I have already worked with `core data` but I don't feel secure enough. The project mentioned above use `dataModel` to populate the `tableView`. I would appreciate any clue to substitute dataModel with core data on this example tutorial, or any advice to implement fixed table sections using `core data` and how to put the needed objects inside the needed section.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The recommended way to populate a UITableView from Core Data is to use NSFetchedResultsController - its seems a big daunting at first but stick with it, its actually pretty straight forward once you understand the concepts.

Here is a link to the Apple Docs.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsController_Class/Reference/Reference.html